# Why is there an "or" here instead of an "and"?

Tags: conjunctions

> In an interview last year he recalled that he had been asked to
>   identify the owner of everything found at the scene, but had failed to
>   find a match for a piece of cloth that seemed to be of military
>   origin, **or** for a pair of glasses, a pair of skis and a piece of a
>   ski, leading him to suspect that the military had found the tent
>   before the volunteer rescuers. ([telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/10026000/Yuri-Yudin.html))

It seems there needs to be ‘and’ instead of ‘or’ in semantic respect. Why is there an ‘or’?

Comment: *Or* is preferred to *and* in distributing a negative over two or more elements, and *fail to find* is semantically negative: "He did not find this, or this, or that." *And* would be used if there was such a close relationship between the elements that they could be regarded as a 'set'.

Comment: @StoneyB: +100. Boolean logic != English. Computer scientists and mathematicians need to be careful not to confuse the two.

Comment: @StoneyB: Could a "nor" be used? _He was not able to identify the owner of A, nor the owner of B, nor the owner of C_ meaning that A, B, and C **where** found and either had been left by some person not belonging to the group of students, or had been left by the students but Yuri Yudin just did not remember to whom of them these things belonged.

Comment: @Stephen Use of *nor* seems to be getting looser these days. Certainly you **can** use *nor* here, but I wouldn't: I reserve *nor* for **a)** *neither ... nor* and *nor ... nor* constructions and **b)** use as a clause-level conjunction. But I'm old, and my literary tastes are older.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thus: _but he found a match neither for A nor for B nor for C_ is preferable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he had used "and" here, it would sound like he may have found some of the items, but not *all* of them.

It might make more sense if you think of it like this: if they found "a piece of cloth that seemed to be of military origin", "a pair of glasses" **or** "a pair of skis", that would imply that at least one of them had been found. But the "not" means that this is false, so *none* of the items were found.